# In Solr, how can I do a range query on a multi-valued field with prefix?

Tags: solr

This question has some older discussion but I am hoping newer versions might have an answer.  My data contains prefixed multi-valued fields.

ex. CustomProperties:["Age:50", "BMI:25"].

I would like to be able to query BMI:[* TO 26].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then index them as actual fields. Solr won't be able to do proper, integer based range searches when they're just multivalued strings like that.

[Add a CustomProperties_* dynamic field](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/dynamic-fields.html) type mapped as an integer or long (if all your values are integers), then add the values as `CustomProperties_Age` and `CustomProperties_BMI`. Querying the values will then be the same as for any other field:

```
q=CustomProperties_BMI:[* TO 26]
```